# cant save the SMS oor MMS

Tags: android

hey guys check out this code...

everything works fine but when ever i get notification of SMS and i pulldown the drawer and click on it.... Nothing happens...
what can i do to store the sms and display it as the android stock messaging application displays themmm...

please help

```
      public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
          /* As we want to display a Notification, we the NotificationManager */
          NotificationManager nm =
               (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
          if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION)) {
               // if(message starts with SMStretcher recognize BYTE)
               StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
               String from = new String();
               String body = new String();

               /* The SMS-Messages are 'hiding' within the extras of the Intent. */
               Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
               if (bundle != null) {
                    /* Get all messages contained in the Intent*/
                   Object[] pduObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                   SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pduObj.length];

                   for(int i=0;i<pduObj.length;i++)
                   {
                           messages[i]=SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pduObj[i]);

                   }
                    /* Feed the StringBuilder with all Messages found. */

                    for (SmsMessage currentMessage : messages){
                        from = currentMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
                        body = currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody();

                         /* Sender-Number */
                         sb.append(from);

                         /* Actual Message-Content */
                         sb.append(body);
                    }
               }
               /* Logger Debug-Output */
               Log.i(LOG_TAG, "[SMSApp] onReceive: " + sb);
               /* Show the Notification containing the Message. */

               int icon=R.drawable.messageicon;

               CharSequence tickerText =  from + ": " + body;
               long when = System.currentTimeMillis();

               Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);
               CharSequence contentTitle = from;
               CharSequence contentText = sb.toString();
               Intent notificationIntent = new Intent();
               PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

               notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);
             //  notification.vibrate = new long[] { 100, 250, 100, 500};
               notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

               nm.notify(1, notification);

               this.abortBroadcast();
               /* Start the Main-Activity 
               Intent i = new Intent(context, SMS.class);
               i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
               context.startActivity(i);*/
          }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It makes sense, this your code is not supposed to start any activity as it is.

The intent (notificationIntent) that you give to the notification manager is the intent that would start the activity if it were initialized to, say,

```
notificationIntent = new Intent(context, SMS.class);
```

Comment: but if i do as u said it opens the main sms sending class menu ... but there arent any sms that i sent before even the sms that is recieved vanishes...

Comment: i'm not really sure what you are trying to do here. The notificationIntent is the intent used by the notification manager once the user clicks on the notification. You put the activity that you want in it.